# How can I add refs in map

Tags: reactjs, dictionary, react-hooks

I don't know how to add refs in map.
I tried this thing but it doesn't work at all.

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  let numRef = useRef([]);

  const mat = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

  console.log(numRef); // 
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        {mat.map((element, idx) => (
          <p ref={numRef.current[idx]} type="text">
            {element}
          </p>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

I want to give all different refs in each p tags.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must have a function in ref which assigns the ref

```
function App() {
  let numRef = useRef([]);

  const mat = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

  console.log(numRef); // 
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        {mat.map((element, idx) => (
          <p ref={(ref) => numRef.current[idx] = ref} type="text">
            {element}
          </p>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```